# How to get a custom MP3 tag via Python?

Tags: python, metadata, mp3, musicbrainz, eyed3

I am working on an algorithm that uses [AcousticBrainz API](https://acousticbrainz.org/). Part of the process is assigning an audio file with a specific UUID that refers to a file in a database. The tag is added via Picard and is present among other tags when checking e.g. via VLC Media Player:

[image]

Is there any way to access these 'custom' tags? I tried to use [eyeD3](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [mutagen](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen), however, I think they only enable accessing specific tags like artist or length of the file.

Can I use eyed3 or mutagen to accomplish the goal? Is there any other tool that enables such operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use either one. These custom tags are stored as user text frames, with the frame ID "TXXX".

Here's some example code with eyeD3:

```python
import eyed3

file = eyed3.load("test.mp3")
for frame in file.tag.frameiter(["TXXX"]):
    print(f"{frame.description}: {frame.text}")
# get a specific tag
artist_id = file.tag.user_text_frames.get("MusicBrainz Artist Id").text
```

And with mutagen (it supports multiple values in each frame, but this seems to violates the ID3 spec; see [this picard PR](https://github.com/metabrainz/picard/pull/634) for the gory details):

```python
from mutagen.id3 import ID3

audio = ID3("test.mp3")
for frame in audio.getall("TXXX"):
    print(f"{frame.desc}: {frame.text}")
# get a specific tag
artist_id = audio["TXXX:MusicBrainz Artist Id"].text[0]
```

You can see how Picard uses mutagen to read these tags here: https://github.com/metabrainz/picard/blob/ee06ed20f3b6ec17d16292045724921773dde597/picard/formats/id3.py#L314-L336

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Eric Johnson! I was unaware of the different tag formats. I was interested in accessing the MBID of the recording and I could not get it through ID3, however, your example and reference to Picard really helped. I ended up needing to read UFID tag, so I used the following:

```
audio = ID3(filepath)
for frame in audio.getall("UFID"):
    print(str(frame.data, 'utf-8'))
```

Posting it here in case anyone needs it in the future.